# Python: make new list based on inputs and two previous lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I'm a newcomer to coding and am using Python 3.6. I am writing some code for an engineering application which involves storing data in lists based upon inputs. I currently have two lists and I want to create a new one based upon inputs and the content of the first two lists. I have shown a simplified example below (not prompting the user for an input to keep things simple).

```
a = 40
a = float(a)

b = 10
b = float(b)

c = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
d = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]

e = [(a / b) if x == 1 else x * y for x in c and y in d]

print(e)
```

So basically I need a way to say *for x in c and y in d* together. In this case the answer I would hope to achieve is `[4, 8, 18, 32, 50]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`e = [(a / b) if x == 1 else x * y for x, y in zip(c, d)]`.

For example, `list(zip([1,2,3], [4,5,6]))` would be `[(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)]`.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much!